# Table name as parameter using PDO/MySQL prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is this possible? e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM :database WHERE id = :id
```

If not, should I just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM ' . $database . ' WHERE id = :id
```

Or is there some other trick I need to learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.
see [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: Oh I didn't see that post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is quite dangerous to pass dynamically built table names in a query. But if it is so much needed by your application, you have to sanitize the data. Since PDO cannot help with this, you have to call [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the table name yourself. Also you will have to enclose the table name with backticks as `table_name`. So prepare the query as:

```
'SELECT * FROM `' . mysql_real_escape_string($database) . '` WHERE id = :id
```

One note: `mysql_real_escape_string` needs an already established connection to the DB.

**EDIT:** But when I think about it, probably is best to match the `$database` variable against your existing tables.

Comment: Yeah, I'm picking them from a fixed list but it's a good point.