# Is it necessary to validate column names when submitting an SQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

In my SQL Queries I am submitting data from forms filled out by the user, and as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884220/dealing-with-quotes-added-by-pdoprepare) it is not possible to parameterize my column names with PDO. This is important because the column names in the query are inserted dynamically based on the field names in the form.
  I can rather easily validate the column names submitted in the $_POST array by simply pulling them out of the database and throwing out any that don't match. Is this a good thing to do to avoid SQL injection or is simply a waste of system resources (as it effectively doubles the execution of any request that relies on the Database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a good thing to do to avoid SQL injection

No.

> or is simply a waste of system resources

No.

It cannot be a waste as it's just a simple select from the system table.

But it is still can be a some sort of injection when a user isn't allowed to some fields. Say, if there is an (imaginary) field "user_role" filled by site admin and a user will have a possibility to define it in the POST, they can alter their access privileges.

So, hardcoding (whitelisting) allowed fields is the only reliable way.

> as it effectively doubles the execution of any request that relies on the Database

Man. Databases intended to be queried. It's the only their purpose. A database that cannot sustain a simple select query is a nonsense. Queries are different. An insert one is  way more heavy than 10 selects. You have to distinguish queries by quality, not quantity.

> the column names in the query are inserted dynamically based on the field names in the form.

Though for the insert/update queries it is quite true, for the SELECT ones it is a BIG SIGN of the bad design. I can stand variable field names in the WHERE/ORDER BY clauses but if you have to vem in the fieldset of table name clauses - your database design is wrong for sure.

Comment: Probably should have been more clear, my SELECT queries do not use dynamic field names. As you said, that would be silly.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from hard-coding the list of columns, you could build a list of columns via another table in your database that you want to allow column querying from, such as

```
QuerableSources
SrcTable      SrcColumn      DescriptToUser
SomeTable     SomeColumn     Column used for
AnotherTable  AnotherColumn  Something Else
etc.
```

Then, you build for example a combobox for a user to pick the "DescriptionToUser" content for easier readability, and YOU control the valid column and table source.

As for the VALUE they are searching for, DEFINITELY Scrub / clean it to prevent SQL-Injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can hard-code the column names to make it faster. You can also cache the pulled table description, so that you don't need to update the code every time table schema changes.