# PDO query with php variables

Tags: php, pdo

Why this line doesn't work:

```
$db_Table = "myTable";

$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO :db_Table VALUES (...

$query->execute(array(
    ':db_Table' => $db_Table,
```

Whereas this one works:

```
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (...
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Yu can't use table names, field names or other identifiers as variables in a prepared statement. You'll need to build your basic query by concatenating or otherwise substituting your identifiers, then `prepare` that result.

Comment: Yes but this one do not works too : `$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $db_Table`.

Answer (score 0):

Tablenames can not be replaced in a PDO Query.

Further information you can find in the following thread 
[Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there are no builtin function for binding table names, you have to do it yourself:

```
$db_Table = "myTable";
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `$db_Table` VALUES (...)");
$query->execute();
```

But that is still not being escaped, one workaround is to have an array of table, then check if it exist:

```
$list_of_tables = array('myTable1', 'myTable2', 'myTable3');
if(!in_array($db_Table, $list_of_tables){
  //table does not exist !
}
```

Comment: What about this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7541933/4086161

Comment: This would not help because you are using pdo